# What will you do when a prospective PhD supervisor does not follow up after an initial positive response?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am applying for a PhD in the UK, and started sending email to contact potential supervisors in January. I have been communicating with a particular professor for about two months. Her response seems positive. For example, she said my research proposal is fantastic. However, she did not give me a firm reply as to whether she or her colleagues is willing to supervise my proposed PhD research topic. Additionally, she did not get back to me, although she said that she will do so last week. How will you handle this situation if you are in my place? Will you still go ahead and submit the application? I have attached the summarized communication between both of us below.

Timeline of our communication: 
8 Jan: I sent the first email to the potential supervisor. 
19 Jan: potential supervisor replied positively, asking for research proposal and CV and writing samples. 
23 Jan: I replied with the documents. 
12 Feb: Seeing that the potential supervisor did not get back to me, I sent a reminder email. 
12 Feb: Potential supervisor replied 2 hours later, saying she will ask her colleagues about my proposal. Also mention that she will get back to me by next week (19 Feb). 
12 Feb: I thanked her for her reply and said I look forward to hearing from her. 
18 Feb: Potential supervisor said she will delay getting back to me, and will email me by next week (26 Feb) instead of tomorrow. 
18 Feb: Again, I thanked her for her reply and said I look forward to hearing from her.

Comment: You should submit the application asap. If the position is starting in October 2021 and is funded by UKRI, interviews may have already taken place since the UKRI funding decision is usually in mid-March. This of course doesn't apply if the position is funded by the individual professor/department/university/external industry partner.

Comment: Do you think I should inform the potential supervisor before submitting the application?